# android onWindowFocusChanged

Tags: android

i want to override the method onWindowFocusChanged, but everytimei write it elcipse gives me a error message saying @override annotation is wrong, which means that i am not overriding the method but creating a new one.

maybe i havnt included the package necessary ???

Comment: If you show the code with the error, we can help you find it. Otherwise, it's just guessing.
That said, if the override error is the only one you have, I'd guess your method signature is not exactly the same as the one you are overriding.

Answer (score 2):

are you using the following code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // your code here
}
```

The difference is there is a Boolean type and a boolean type.  This code gives me no annotation warnings in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to you having Java version set to something other than 1.6. Go to project->properties->Java compiler and set compliance level to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Check your super-class and get the method signature from there, including visibility (private, protected, public...) return type, method name, and arguments.